# How to read Excel file in Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read `.xlsx` file in `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX`

```
#!/home/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $oExcel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
die "You must provide a filename to $0 to be parsed as an Excel file"
unless @ARGV;


my $oBook = $oExcel->Parse($ARGV[0]);
my($iR, $iC, $oWkS, $oWkC);
print "FILE  :", $oBook->{File} , "\n";
print "COUNT :", $oBook->{SheetCount} , "\n";
print "AUTHOR:", $oBook->{Author} , "\n" if defined $oBook->{Author};
```

When I execute the perl, then I got the message as below,

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at conv2xlsxml.pl line 64.
FILE  :
Use of uninitialized value in print at conv2xlsxml.pl line 65.
COUNT :
```

How do I correctly access excel file in `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you read that was the correct way to use SpreadSheet::ParseXLSX?

I don't know the module at all well but, reading [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX), it says:

> This module returns data using classes from [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel), so for the most part, it should just be a drop-in replacement.

And reading the documentation for Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, I don't see any examples that access the data inside the object directly in the way that your code does. Instead, there are methods to access the data inside the workbook object.

> **Workbook**
>
> A `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook` is created via the `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` `parse()` method:
>
> ```
> my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
> my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');
> ```
>
> The main methods of the Workbook class are:
>
> ```
> $workbook->worksheets()
> $workbook->worksheet()
> $workbook->worksheet_count()
> $workbook->get_filename()
> ```
>
> These more commonly used methods of the Workbook class are outlined below. The other, less commonly used, methods are documented in [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet).

So, instead of `$oBook->{File}`, it looks like you should be called `$oBook->getfilename()` and instead of `$oBook->{SheetCount}`, it looks like you should be calling `$oBook->worksheet_count()`. I can't see any obvious way to get the author of the spreadsheet.

Oh, and seeing you using `new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` makes me think you're using very old documentation. That's "indirect object notation" and we've been recommending you don't use it for about twenty years. And, of course, you should be making a Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX object, not a Spreadsheet::ParseExcel object.

```
my $oBook = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
```

Comment: I just want to read the excel file and make another XML file. So I don't need to modify the excel file. Sir Could you please recommend me the Perl module? which module is prefer to read?

Comment: @Monica: Everything I have written above is about reading an Excel file. Nothing is about modifying the file. I think you are using the correct module.

Comment: @Monica: Where did you find information telling you to write code like `$oBook->{File}`?

Comment: Sir I got from https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.naver?blogId=enthusiasm&logNo=20132272749&navType=by  but I think 
 http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/kr/library/l-pexcel/  is dead

Comment: @Monica: Ok, it looks like that was an older version of the interface that was removed from the module back in 2009. The blog post is from 2011 - so it was out of date before it was published :-) It's always a good idea to read the official documentation on CPAN instead of random old blog posts.